# Why is the probability of a random walk reaching 1 (in n steps) squared greater than the probability of it reaching 2 (in n steps)?

Tags: probability, markov-process, random-walk

Let $S_n$ be a simple random walk. i.e.

$$
S_n = \sum_{t=1}^n X_t,
$$
where ${X_t}$ are i.i.d random variables with

$$
X_t =
\begin{cases}
+1,  &  \textrm{w/ probability } p \\
-1, &  \textrm{w/ probability } q=1-p
\end{cases}
$$

Let $$P_k(n) = \mathbb{P}(\textrm{reach } x=k \textrm{  within the } n \textrm{ first steps})$$

Is there an easy way to prove $P_1(n)^2 \geq P_2(n)$? I tried to think of ways through induction or relating $P_1(n)^2$ to $P_2(2n)$. To no avail.

Comment: Have you tried to explain how to get to 2 with $P_1(n)$?

Comment: Have you considered the Chapman-Kolmogorov equations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin {array}{}
P_2(n) &=& \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}P_1 (n-k)( P_1(k)-P_1 (k-1))
\\&\leq& \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}P_1 (n)( P_1(k)-P_1 (k-1))
\\&\leq& P_1(n) \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (P_1(k)-P_1 (k-1))= P_1 (n) P_1 (n-1) \\
&\leq& P_1 (n) P_1 (n)\end {array}
$$

Where $( P_1(k)-P_1 (k-1))$ is the probability to reach position 1 in the $k$-th step (which is different from within $k$ steps). And then $( P_1(k)-P_1 (k-1))P_1 ({n-k})$ is then the probability to reach another step in the direction 1 after being the first time in position 1 at the $k $-th step.